# Woocommerce - How to show Order details (my-account) on a separate page

Tags: php, wordpress, woocommerce, wordpress-theming

Right now, in woocommerce the shortcode `[woocommerce_my_account]` displays the entire "My Account" page with all the tabbed options.

I only want to show the order details (found under the Orders tab) on a separate page.

So, can I just use the woocommerce template `orders.php` (woocommerce/templates/myaccount/orders.php) and use it on a blank new page or is there a better way to go about it?

Answer (score 13, accepted):

Woocommerce has function woocommerce_account_orders() which includes Orders template. You can follow the below steps to display only orders on a separate page.

**Step-1:** Place below code in your theme's functions.php (Place in child theme if you have created).

```
function woocommerce_orders() {
    $user_id = get_current_user_id();
    if ($user_id == 0) {
         return do_shortcode('[woocommerce_my_account]'); 
    }else{
        ob_start();
        wc_get_template( 'myaccount/my-orders.php', array(
            'current_user'  => get_user_by( 'id', $user_id),
            'order_count'   => $order_count
         ) );
        return ob_get_clean();
    }

}
add_shortcode('woocommerce_orders', 'woocommerce_orders');
```

**Step-2:** Place shortcode [woocommerce_orders] in any pages in admin side and check on front end.

Above Code will display orders if customer is loggedin otherwise it will display woocommerce's login/registration page.

If you want to **hide "Orders"** tabbed option which is on "My Account" Page then go to Admin Side and then *Woocommerce > Settings > Accounts (tab*) where you can see "My account endpoints", empty "orders" field there. It will hide "Orders" from frontend "My Account" page.

**Edit:** Make sure that you check on frontend loggedin as "Customer" user and that customer user has atleast one order placed otherwise blank page will display there.